# Bootstrap - adding two text links on the right side of nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to put two text link on the right side of my nav bar.

Register | Contact Us

How would I do that based on my bootply?

Here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/waaBbWFaI1

Here's my HTML:

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container topnav">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://red.org/wp-content/plugins/a8c-stripe/img/red_logo.png" alt="Onvia Exchange">
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 3 you use an unordered list with the class `nav navbar-nav navbar-right`, like so. (click on full screen so you can see it in desktop view)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container topnav">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://red.org/wp-content/plugins/a8c-stripe/img/red_logo.png" alt="Onvia Exchange">
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Register</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="./">Register <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```